# easy-menu-define: how to display menu only in mode-line

Tags: mode-line, easy-menu

I'm using `easy-menu-define` to diplay a menu in the mode-line on the activation of a minor-mode:

```el
(if biblio-editing-min-mode
    (easy-menu-define biblio-edit-menu biblio-editing-min-mode-map
      "BibEdit"
      '("BibEdit"
...
```

When I activate the minor-mode the menu is diplayed both on mode-line and menu-bar. I want the menu to be displayed only on the mode-line. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with:

```el
(if biblio-editing-min-mode
    (easy-menu-define biblio-edit-menu biblio-editing-min-mode-map
      "BibEdit"
      '("BibEdit"
        :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))
...
```